# a link in <nav> suddenly behaves like a has a hover that's different from the other links

Tags: html, css

Just to start off, I am new to html and CSS and have only been coding for the last two weeks or so. I might have missed something or overseen some vital thing. But I hope you can help me anyway.

I implemented a simple contact form in one of my pages, which resulted in my links behaving differently. I have made it so that my links have a hover function, which changes the border color and background color from white and black to black and white. Pretty simple. After I implemented the contact form these links now behave like I have made a a:active in my css that makes my links text and border go from white to a blue-ish/purple color. I have build the structure of this contact form from top to bottom multiple times to see where the error takes place, but I can't seem to find it. Funny thing is, if I remove the styling of this contact form, the links still change to the blue-ish/purple color, which makes me believe that the css isn't the problem but rather the html.

I've used  in this contact form, which I haven't used before. I don't know if it might have some tag attributes that makes my links turn purple.

Hope you can help.

Here's my code:

```css
/*contact form*/
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit] {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=question] {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*hover code*/
nav div:hover a {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 height:62px;
}

nav div:hover a:hover {
 background-color:#E3E3E3;
 color:black;
 border-color:black;
}

nav div:hover a:hover {
 background-color:#E3E3E3;
 color:black;
 border-color:black;
}

nav div:hover a:first-child {
 background-color:#E3E3E3;
 color:black;
}

a:hover{
 transition: 0.4s linear;
 background-color:#E3E3E3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    Fornavn og Efternavn
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>E-mail:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="mail">
    <br>Spørgsmål:
    <br>
    <input type="question" name="comment" size="50">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can You add a working snippet?

Comment: Add your whole css with the hover function

Comment: I think this is the `:visited` pseudo-class for links that is purple in most browsers’ `html.css` default style sheet. Just add a rule for `a:visited`.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert what would such rule be? I've already defined how a visited link should look like, so I don't see how another rule would help?

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig I've added the css with the hover function

Comment: You have a nav tag, but I don't see it in your html, can you post that code as well?